# Why do my initializations in Android Studio do nothing?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm just getting in to android developing and I've been having the same problems when it comes to initializing just about anything before use. My app always crashes due to trying to use methods on a null object even though I initialize it like people do on other questions asked on this site.

```
ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);
```

Why is this line not working in my onCreate? I have private LinearLayout ll; earlier in the code but for some reason it does nothing. I had a similar problem with an EditText that I used a view that I made equal to an inflator but that doesn't seem to work in this context. I'm just confused as to why that line above works for everyone but me. slider is the name of another LinearLayout in an xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have invoked setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_for_activity) in onCreate callback. It sets the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_for_activity);
    // do something
}
```

After this if you try to use findViewById, it refers to above layout for finding views.

If above is not helpful, share the code snippet.

Comment: Shouldn't this work?

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    PopupWindow pw;
    EditText edit, edit2;
    String name;
    String password;
    private LinearLayout ll;
    private float startX;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

Comment: I've been the line ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider); before and after setContentView and nothing seems to change

Comment: 1. setContentView(..) must be before you try to use findViewById(..)
2. R.id.slider must exist in the layout you are actually setting in for your Activity in context. So, MainActivty if having setContentView(R.layout.my_act), my_act.xml must have a LinearLayout with id=slider
3. You might check for any nested hierarchy of layouts
  <RL>
    <LL>
    <LL>
  </RL>